# No inserta datos de la base de datos MysQL desde PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Mi problema es que quiero enviar los datos por POST y al momento de enviarlos no me los envia
este es mi codigo

```
<?php
include "conexion.php";
if(isset($_POST['save_task'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $contraseña = $_POST['contraseña'];
    $fecha_creacion = $_POST['fecha_creacion'];
    $fecha_caducacion = $_POST['fecha_caducacion'];
    $tiempo = $_POST['tiempo_duracion'];
    $estado = $_POST['estado'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO cuentas(email, contraseña, fecha_creacion,
     fecha_caducacion, tiempo_duracion, estado) VALUES ('$email',
     '$contraseña', '$fecha_creacion', '$fecha_caducacion',
     '$tiempo', '$estado')";
     $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
     if(!$result) {
         die("Query Failed");
     }
     echo "Saving";
}
?>
```

Esta es DB 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Tal vez el error está desde el formulario, edita tu pregunta y añade el formulario por favor! Otra observación es en el sql los campos deben de llevan comillas simples. ¿Has hecho un var_dump($_POST);  para saber si están llegando los valores?

Comment: si, esto me aparece cuando hago el var_dump
array(7) { ["email"]=> string(13) "fas@gmail.com" ["contraseña"]=> string(4) "uuyu" ["fecha_creacion"]=> string(11) "11111-11-11" ["fecha_caducacion"]=> string(11) "11111-11-11" ["tiempo_duracion"]=> string(3) "111" ["estado"]=> string(2) "11" ["save_task"]=> string(9) "Save Task" } Query Failed

Comment: acostumbrate a añadir tu codigo `$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);` dentro de un bloque try/catch, o añadirle  `or die(mysqli_error($con));` para ver los errores de la consulta o el problema que te da.

Comment: Es muy probable que **el problema sea la `ñ` que estás usando sea en el nombre de columna, en el name del input y/o en el nombre de variable PHP**, te recomiendo que evites el uso de `ñ` y caracteres especiales en los contextos antes indicados, porque si no tienes una codificación adecuada el código se rompe en cualquier punto. Si no puedes cambiar la `ñ` en todo cambiala al menos donde puedas, sea como sea, debes saber que  tienes que cuidar la codificación, haciendo que ésta sea la misma en todos los niveles: HTML, PHP, Base de Datos (internamente y en la conexión mysqli).